# Volume of convex polytope with $\mathcal{H}$-representation

Tags: convex-analysis, volume, polyhedra, polytopes, discrete-geometry

Consider the convex polytope $\mathcal{P} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\mathcal{H}$-representation

$$\mathcal{P} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n\colon Ax \leq b\},$$

where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$. How to compute the volume of $\mathcal{P}$? (Can I convert this problem into an optimization problem?) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this is not possible in polynomial time (unless P=NP).
You can do it in exponential time by so called *triangulation*, that is by dissecting your polytope into simplices whose volume can be computed using a closed formula.

Have a look here: https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-011-0924-6_17

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer and the reference :-)